# Reverse-order Negative BarSpacing

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have some data for a bar chart:

```
testdata = Map[{1, #} &, RandomReal[{-0.5, 4}, {3, 2}], {2}]
(* {{{1, 3.30023}, {1, 3.814}}, {{1, -0.353959}, {1, -0.364447}}, {{1, 
     1.82514}, {1, 2.56824}}} *)

RectangleChart[testdata, BarOrigin -> Left, Frame -> True, 
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, BarSpacing -> {-0.2, 0.6}]
```

[image]

But what I really want is for the shorter, red bars to overlap *on top* of the blue bars, not underneath.

```
RectangleChart[Reverse /@ testdata, BarOrigin -> Left, Frame -> True, 
  ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red}, BarSpacing -> {-0.2, 0.6}]
```

[image]

That works, but the red bars only overlap if they are *above* the blue bars. If I had set `BarOrigin->Bottom`, the red bars would then be on the right.

```
RectangleChart[Reverse /@ testdata, Frame -> True, 
  ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red}, BarSpacing -> {-0.2, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Conceptually this is because later data prints after earlier data, so groups of bars on the right or at the top are "later" and print on top of the "earlier" bars on the left or below.

This makes sense to me, but not to the person I am drawing the graph for. Is there any way to reverse the bar ordering such that the bars at the bottom of the group overlap on top of the upper bars when one has negative `BarSpacing`?

Comment: Does this work `MapAt[Rotate[#, -90 Degree] &, 
 RectangleChart[testdata, Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red},  BarSpacing -> {-0.2, 0.6}, Axes -> False, BarOrigin -> Bottom], {1}]` (with some extra work on tick labels)?

Comment: @kguler - It would need to be `RectangleChart[Reverse/@testdata...`. That is inspired, but how I'd then get that into our crazy custom charting functions is a challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like kugler approach, this is another one. Not sure if it is going to work for general case but it should.

```
RectangleChart[testdata, BarOrigin -> Left, Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
                         BarSpacing -> {-0.2, 0.6}
              ] /. x : {{__, _Tooltip} ..} :> Reverse@x
```

> [image]

Of course for `PerformanceGoal:>"Speed"` there are no `Tooltips` but it is easy to handle too.

```
RectangleChart[testdata, BarOrigin -> Left, Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
                         BarSpacing -> {-0.2, 0.6}, PerformanceGoal :> "Speed"
              ] /. x : {{__, _Rectangle} ..} :> Reverse@x
```

Comment: Ah, clever, kubanator! +1

Comment: @rasher Hehe :) thanks.

Comment: This is excellent! I'm just testing if it works with our crazy custom functions.

Comment: @Verbeia I'm glad I could help :)